# Excel VBA - SendKeys "{F2}" - keeps toggling num-lock

Tags: excel, vba, sendkeys, num-lock

After using setting a cell to select and then using `SendKeys "{F2}"` (So that the cell is ready for input) it likes to toggle num-lock every time this is ran.

I have seen people say to use `SendKeys "{NUMLOCK}", True` after the `SendKeys "{F2}"` but tat did nto help. even tried adding `Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")` between the two comands, but it still keeps toggling.

I have also read its a bug with Excel/VBA.

Is there a better solutions? I need to select the cell and then force it into edit mode in order for some validation checks to work properly, else it bypasses the check if it just selects the cell, the could continue on, forcing it into edit make it so they have to make a change if not and they leave the cell the validation kicks in again.

I also found this code and tried, but that doe not work, it just keeps toggling

```
Dim wshshell As Object
Set wshshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wshshell.SendKeys "{NUMLOCK}"
Set wshshell = Nothing
```

Even tried this and replaced with F2 but it still toggled numlock.

I need numlock to stay on at all times. is there another way to invoke the edit cell instead of F2?

Comment: "in order for some validation checks to work properly" maybe you can expand on that a little.

Comment: `I need to select the cell and then force it into edit mode in order for some validation checks to work properly` You cannot run any code once the cell is in edit mode. Excel freezes and waits for you to come out of edit mode. Having said that, there is a complex code using APIs which captures every keystroke in edit mode but I doubt that will be of any help to you...

Comment: `I need numlock to stay on at all times.` Then you probably don't want to use `SendKeys`.  Perhaps there is a way to use `SendKeys` and be certain num/caps lock doesn't change state but I haven't heard of it.  You can check the keystate and turn it back on inperceptively but the doesn't meet your requirement of remaining `on at all times`.  So, I think your best bet is to drop `SendKeys` and send messages to the target window via API